# how to handle question offering payment

Tags: discussion, questions, review

From https://stackoverflow.com/q/14099385/836214

Is it ok on SO to offer payments for answers? This seems very out of place.  How is this sort of thing normally handled?

Comment: How's it handled?  By editing out the crap and telling the user to knock it off, that's how.

Comment: For the record, there are "external" sites (not related to Stack Exchange) where people offer real money bounties for answering Stack Overflow questions. Don't have time to find the discussion here on Meta, but I'm sure I've seen it and such sites exist and are legal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit out the WILL PAY FOR ADVICE part, and comment that we don't really facilitate that on SO.

Also, check if the question ought to be closed and flag/VTC it as such. I'm not too sure if it should be closed as anything, but it *is* a rather low quality post.

Comment: This one in particular is low quality without the trying to offer payment; I guess I was looking for a more general way to handle it, even if it was better quality otherwise.