# Advertize monetary payment for my SO question

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties, advertising

So I asked [Add browser action button in internet explorer BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364178/add-browser-action-button-in-internet-explorer-bho) and I didn't get any answers yet.

I was wondering if it's legitimate to offer a sum of money for answering it. I will offer a bounty tomorrow anyway but I want to attract more people.

So **may I advertize a monetary reward for answering the question on the question**? I'm fully aware that the answer will still be under the CC license, and anyone (not just me) may use it later - I really don't mind.

BTW - I'm kind of surprised I couldn't find a duplicate (but then again I suck at meta search)

Comment: ^How shoul dit be ensured that the money is actually transfered?

Comment: Well, you don't mind about re-use it - but may be some other person will be against it. It's complicated and I doubt all licensing problems that possibly will appear are all clear. But possibility itself seems to be interesting. Let we gain some money for our efforts! :p (but I'm doubt that there will be some mechanics of __controlling__ that payments)

Comment: @Devolus I represent a company and I'm very active in Stack Overflow. It's an interesting question but as a company our reputation is worth a lot more than a small contract. $200 (what I want to offer) is really not a lot of money for us to invest in getting an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I don't doubt that you would do the transfer, but for such a mechanism, I guess there would be needed some control to ensure it for everybody.

Comment: @JanDvorak that question a feature request - I request no additional feature to the system - I just want to know if it's OK with the site to offer money in the question and if anyone has done it before.

Comment: @Benjamin while true (took me a second read to realize he asked to integrate it into the bounty system) Shog point is still valid: it's a bad idea and will only encourage flame wars and answers posted just for sake of money.

Comment: The corollary of your question is [how to handle question offering payment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160944/how-to-handle-question-offering-payment) and tangentially related is [Why was question deleted? … because I offered payment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153537/why-was-question-deleted-because-i-offered-payment).

Comment: I know of this Nigerian prince who would be willing to handle the transfer of the money =o)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards thanks, these are good reads. I just want to emphasize that my question is simple and clear and I believe it is generally applicable - that is, it will help many users who're looking into develop browser extensions and not just me.

Comment: You have https://bountify.co it was mentioned here from time to time, appears still active and looks like those who answer know their stuff.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards that seems to be a duplicate, although he is offering a lot less money for a less generally applicable problem that would benefit the community a lot less. In my case I want to pay people to burst a propiatry information bubble and give knowledge to the masses. Still, reading those questions I now see why allowing it in this case might cause a lot of problems in the general case. Thanks. Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: $200 is ridiculously low, any expert will tell you to get lost.  Or, more likely, just ignore you.  You can only get the answer you need for free.

Comment: @UphillLuge This is a general problem applicable to many people. The idea was not to "contract" someone - the idea was to give a nice monetary reward for someone who posts an answer (for a general problem) in StackOverflow for the benefit of the community. Nothing like the contract where I get to 'own' the code, it's still CC and it's still like any of your 13K answers. More like writing an answer and getting an extra buck for something you'd do anyway for fun and contribution for helping someone out.